# How to integrate StyleCop into Tfs 2010

Tags: tfs, stylecop

I need to run StyleCop rules check when gatecheckin into tfs2010.
But I dont know how to configure this.
Please help.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The easiest way is to change from using SyleCop to using Code Analysis which is built into VS2010.

If you must use StyleCop you need to get it to run as an activity on the XAML Workflow used during the build. The easiest way is to create an activity that runs StyleCop with the options as parameters. You can then surface those options to the Process settings on the build definition.

I would check out http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/

Comment: VS2010 Code Analysis is integrated fxCop, not StyleCop. Code Analysis analyses .NET assemblies and is thus language agnostic. StyleCop analyses C# source files and is thus C# specific.